# Gradle не собирает Runnable Jar

Tags: java, jar, gradle

Недавно переехал в **Eclipse** со штатных средств по сборке на Gradle, намучался с тасками и самый последний поставил меня в тупик. Мне нужно собрать **Runnable Jar** файл и я использую таск **"jar"**(только его, если важно). В итоге выдается обрезок в виде 27 кб, где не хватает внутренностей, и он не запускается. Раньше запускающийся jar у меня весил 200-300 кб.

*build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'java'  
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'formatter.FormatterMain'
jar {
    baseName = 'PostMaker'
    version =  '2.0_Alpha'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}


test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
    }
}
```

P.S.: Также нужна помощь в подключении сторонних библиотек в виде jar файлов, возможно, проблема из-за них, в jarнике их не нахожу. Хотя Eclipse запускал и без них нормально.

Comment: А Вы проверили пути нахождения файлов? Это наиболее распостраненная проблема)

Comment: @roman-kozin , каких именно? Классы, библиотеки(клал, как было описано на stackoverflow, в отдельный пакет)?

Кстати, очень напоминает то, что выдает стоковый "Export>Java>JAR file", этот тоже весит мало и не запускается.

Допускаю что использовал не тот таск, но каких-либо других подходящих не вижу.

Comment: Мне кажется jar собирается нормально, просто вы его неправильно запускаете. И обычно внутрь jar никаких библиотек не кладут. Про classpath что-нибудь слышали?

Comment: Слышал, но не использовал. Мне кажется без ущерба функционированию jar не может просто так уменьшиться в 10 раз

Comment: Попробуйте вместо jar использовать build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось намного проще, чем я думал:

```
manifest.attributes("Main-Class": mainClassName);
```

Эта строчка, добавленная в блок jar в файле **build.gradle**, решила проблему с исполняемостью jar файла.

`mainClassName` - переменная с главным классом.

Comment: Для полноты ответа:
jar{
  manifest{
     manifest.attributes('Main-Class' : 'mainClassName');
  }
}

Где MainClass - header, mainClassName - value